# Filter available time slot for today in laravel using carbon

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, php-carbon

I want to filter available time for today for a user. He can only make an appointment for a time slot that is bigger than time right now + 6 hours. But the problem is when + 6 hours transfers to the next day so it could be like 00:44 next day and in that case when it compares to the time slots it shows that time slot at 8:00 for example is bigger than 00:44 so it shows that time slot for today although it shouldn't be possible to make an appointment for that time slot anymore. Is there a way to filter it in the eloquent? I basically want addHours to stop if it reaches 23:59. My Eloquent function:

```
        $times_today = TimeSlot::where('status', 1)
        ->whereTime('time', '>', Carbon::now()->addHours(6))
        ->get();
```

Comment: $dtToronto = Carbon::create('2022','8','2', 23,59,59, 'America/Toronto');

Comment: Use whereDate instead of wherTime if you want to take date into account

Answer (score 0):

Carbon provides a `tomorrow()` function that you can use in the same way you've made use of `now()`.

I assume you don't want people booking appointments up until midnight (although perhaps you do?) so I would also use the `subHours()` function to limit timeslots to before a certain time.

```
$times_today = TimeSlot::where('status', 1)
        ->whereTime('time', '>', Carbon::now()->addHours(6))
        ->whereTime('time', '<', Carbon::tomorrow()->subHours(2))
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create timestamp for specfic time using create function with time zone then you can aad hours in current timestamp by using  Carbon::now()->addHours(6)

```
$dtToronto = Carbon::create('2022','8','2', 23,59,59, 'America/Toronto'); 
    $times_today = TimeSlot::where('status', 1)
    ->whereTime('time', '>', Carbon::now()->addHours(6))
    ->whereTime('time', '<=', $dtToronto)->get();
```

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers.  Explain what the code does and how it solves the problem.